# Problems running Zeppelin - port related

Tags: websocket, apache-zeppelin

I am on OSX and trying to run Zeppelin 0.10.1 on latest Java 8.

I am starting the daemon with no configuration changes and without configuring authentication.

When I try to visit the frontend, I see no default interpreters in the dropdown list, and I am not able to create a new notebook.

At the server side, I see my websockets are being closed in the Zeppelin log:

```
INFO [2023-06-01 11:15:54,824] ({qtp1173643169-30} NotebookServer.java[onClose]:472) - Closed connection to 127.0.0.1:51232 (1002) Unknown opcode: 7
 WARN [2023-06-01 11:15:54,824] ({qtp1173643169-30} ConnectionManager.java[removeUserConnection]:148) - Closing connection that is absent in user connections
 INFO [2023-06-01 11:15:55,984] ({qtp1173643169-20} NotebookServer.java[onOpen]:244) - New connection from 127.0.0.1:51278
 INFO [2023-06-01 11:16:06,002] ({qtp1173643169-20} NotebookServer.java[onClose]:472) - Closed connection to 127.0.0.1:51278 (1002) Unknown opcode: 7
 WARN [2023-06-01 11:16:06,002] ({qtp1173643169-20} ConnectionManager.java[removeUserConnection]:148) - Closing connection
```

Chrome Developer tools shows that the websocket was closed with unknown opcode 7:

```
CloseEvent {isTrusted: true, wasClean: false, code: 1002, reason: 'Unknown opcode: 7', type: 'close', …}
isTrusted
: 
true
bubbles
: 
false
cancelBubble
: 
false
cancelable
: 
false
code
: 
1002
composed
: 
false
currentTarget
: 
WebSocket {url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws', readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: ƒ, onerror: ƒ, …}
defaultPrevented
: 
false
eventPhase
: 
0
reason
: 
"Unknown opcode: 7"
```

I then tried to change the port to 9000, to check we weren't clashing with the Spark UI as recommended in a few places.

The problem is when I change the port, the front-end still tries to connect to a websocket on port 8080, as though that is hard coded in the front-end and the configured port value isn't used.  I tried clearing various caches at this stage but it still tries to connect to a web socket in port 8080.

I am confused as it's a standard setup and out of the box binary download and the last release was in February.

I have tried various hostnames, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 etc.  I have tried various browsers, disabled extensions etc.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Comment: It appears if I change the port to anything other than 9000 in the config file then this works.  There is something strange about port 9000.  So I am up and running, but will leave the question open.